# Two cells referencing same data - when one's reference changes so does the other's?

Tags: excel, graph, charts, reference, trendline

I have a template that I use in Excel for calculating protein concentrations and various other things. Data is entered and is always in the same place, but the linear graph will have changing slope and intercept values.

I need to obtain both the slope and intercept as easily and in the least complicated way as possible.

Right now I have two cells - one for slope and one for intercept -that reference the same x and y values as the graph. However, if the graph needs to use five points instead of nine, then I have to change the data for the graph, and then the x and the y for both slope and intercept - 5 "changes".

What I need is either a way to extract the slope and intercept straight from the graph - with the range being directly linked to the range used by the graph - or to have independent cells for both slope and intercept, but link their references to the same reference (at least as each other but preferably the graph as well). Example:

```
A1:A9 is the x-values and B1:B9 is the y-values.
Graph with a linear trendline is calculated.
C1 is the slope of the trendline.
D1 is the intercept of the trendline.
```

Occasionally, the graph will have a trendline only from values within the above range (A1:A5, A3:A7, etc - always in a row though, not separated).

I need the slope and intercept cells to reference the same data references for the graph's trendline - if the graph references A1:A9/B1:B9, then the cells should too. If the graph is changed and references A2:A6/B2:B6, then the cells should automatically reference those.Basically I am trying to make it so that when the range is altered for the graph the slope and intercept cells automatically adjust.

What would be the easiest way to do this? I've tried everything I can think of.

Nothing is ruled out as an option. There is only one rule - it must be 100% in Excel - no external programs or other files. It must be transferable so that if I send the file to a colleague then it would operate 100% the same.

Comment: What do you use to calculate the slope and intercept right now? Are they formula's directly in the cells? Or is that what you're looking for? I ask because most formulas in excel will ignore blanks.

Comment: You could change the range of the calculated cells in the worksheet, and have the graph draw a line based on that information, instead of pulling the calculated slope/intercept from excel.

Comment: Right now I am simply using the SLOPE and INTERCEPT formulas. But that means that requires changing the x and y values independently for each - making 4x total changes on those alone.

Comment: Graph's use the X and Y values such as A1:A9 and B1:B9. If you change the X value range to A2:A6, then the Y value range will automatically change from B1:B9 into B2:B6 - matching the change made. I want this type of function, but in a cell. So if I do the above, then not only would the graph change, but the slope and intercept cells would change.

Comment: Basically I am trying to make multiple cells reference the exact same range of references (such as A1:A9) and I want to make it so that if that reference range changes for one, then it changes for the other(s). This is what you see in a graph when you change the range of the X values and the Y values change identically.

Comment: For the slope and intercept formulas, use the "Indirect" formula. For example, anywhere you reference the range, A1:A9, use "Indirect(X3)". Then, in cell X3, put "A1:A9" (without the quotes). All range changes only need to be done to cell X3. Then, in the graph, draw a line using the information in the cells containing "Slope" and "Intercept", so that when the cells change value, the graph does as well. This way, the line and points are all dependent on cell X3. I don't think the indirect formula works in graphs, though, so if you're plotting points, you'd need a different solution.

Comment: The above works, but you have to manually type in the specific range - about the same if not "more" work than just changing the range by having the formulas reference the specific cells themselves. Is there a way to use indirect, but instead of typing it in every time being able to click the desired range? As is done when editing what cells you want a graph to reference?

Comment: If having all your formulas reference one cell and then just changing the one is more work then what you do now, either I don't understand your problem or I don't have a solution for you. Good luck.

Comment: It's not 'more work' per se, but just not truly different. The goal is if I have many different cells and they reference the same thing that a graph does, then I would have imagined there was a way so that when you change the data from the graph it would change the same reference from another cell.

There is no 'problem' as in something not working. I just assumed there would be a way to 'link'/'mirror' references amongst multiple cells. And since formulas show the colored window/box, I assumed that would be an option as well.

Sorry if this seems small

Answer (score 0):

I would look at using named ranges for the x and y values, then have the graph and SLOPE/INTERCEPT formulas refer to the same named ranges. For example:

- named range "x_values" refers to "A1:A9"
- named range "y_values" refers to "B1:B9"

Note: the graph will need the sheet or workbook name prefixing the named range.

This may not seem useful at first, because as soon as you manually drag the graph range, it will no longer refer to the named range, and differ to the SLOPE/INTERCEPT formulas. But I would refrain from doing that, and look at making the named ranges dynamic instead.
This is done by assigning a formula to the named ranges. The formula could adjust the size of the range by referring to other cell values. For example:

- cell "C1" represents the range offset (starting point)
- cell "C2" represents the range size (number of points)
- formula "=OFFSET($A$1, $C$1, 0, $C$2)" can be assigned to the "x_values" named range
- formula "=OFFSET($B$1, $C$1, 0, $C$2)" can be assigned to the "y_values" named range

Then all you have to do is adjust cells C1 and C2 to update both the graph and the SLOPE/INTERCEPT formulas.

The formulas in the named ranges can be made smarter by automatically re-sizing the ranges. For example, if you want to ignore blank cells at the beginning or end of the range, you can use something like this:

```
=OFFSET($A$1, MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(($A$1:$A$9)<>0,0),0)-1, 0, COUNTA($A$1:$A$9))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. The typing is significantly lower and when the two cells (such as C1 and/or C2 from the above) changes, the graph, slope cell, intercept cell, all change identically.